# PHP problem executing from backquotes

Tags: php, exec

I have the following PHP code:

```
 for($i=1; $i <= 25; $i++){
        $ifoids = $ifoids." ifPhysAddress.$i "."ifType.$i "."ifSpeed.$i "."ifDescr.$i "."ifOperStatus.$i";
if($i%12==0){
                echo $idoids;
        $rtable=$rtable.`snmpget -Os -Ov -Oe -Oq -Ot -v 1 -c public $ip $ifoids`;
        $ifoids="";
        echo $i.": ".$rtable."</br>";       
}}
```

The second time that it tries to execut the snmpget command, the values sent of the `$ifoid` variable are the same as the first time. Although a `print()` just before the command would print a correct value.

Comment: Not I, looks to me like it should work.  What problem are you actually experiencing that makes you think it's not working?

Comment: When it enters the if the second time ($i==24) the values sent to the command are the same as the first iteration. I saw that with the echo inside.

Comment: Works for me buddy - http://codepad.org/u0xIygUu

Comment: It works for me too, the variable `$ifoids` it's reseted.

Comment: Ok I kept testing and it does change the variable, but not on inside the command `snmpget` the second time it enters, although the values of $ifoids are different it still gives me the same output as the previous iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the enclosed example, you should be able to see that $ifoids is being cleared down.

```
for($i=1; $i <= 25; $i++) {
        $ifoids = $ifoids." ifPhysAddress.$i "."ifType.$i "."ifSpeed.$i "."ifDescr.$i "."ifOperStatus.$i";

        if($i%12==0) {
            $rtable = "snmpget -Os -Ov -Oe -Oq -Ot -v 1 -c public $ip $ifoids";
            $ifoids="";
            echo $i.": ".$rtable."</br>";
        }
}
```

**Example output:**

note: line-breaks added for clarity

```
12: snmpget -Os -Ov -Oe -Oq -Ot -v 1 -c public
ifPhysAddress.1 ifType.1 ifSpeed.1 ifDescr.1 ifOperStatus.1
ifPhysAddress.2 ifType.2 ifSpeed.2 ifDescr.2 ifOperStatus.2
ifPhysAddress.3 ifType.3 ifSpeed.3 ifDescr.3 ifOperStatus.3
ifPhysAddress.4 ifType.4 ifSpeed.4 ifDescr.4 ifOperStatus.4
ifPhysAddress.5 ifType.5 ifSpeed.5 ifDescr.5 ifOperStatus.5
ifPhysAddress.6 ifType.6 ifSpeed.6 ifDescr.6 ifOperStatus.6
ifPhysAddress.7 ifType.7 ifSpeed.7 ifDescr.7 ifOperStatus.7
ifPhysAddress.8 ifType.8 ifSpeed.8 ifDescr.8 ifOperStatus.8
ifPhysAddress.9 ifType.9 ifSpeed.9 ifDescr.9 ifOperStatus.9
ifPhysAddress.10 ifType.10 ifSpeed.10 ifDescr.10 ifOperStatus.10
ifPhysAddress.11 ifType.11 ifSpeed.11 ifDescr.11 ifOperStatus.11
ifPhysAddress.12 ifType.12 ifSpeed.12 ifDescr.12 ifOperStatus.12</br>

24: snmpget -Os -Ov -Oe -Oq -Ot -v 1 -c public
ifPhysAddress.13 ifType.13 ifSpeed.13 ifDescr.13 ifOperStatus.13
ifPhysAddress.14 ifType.14 ifSpeed.14 ifDescr.14 ifOperStatus.14
ifPhysAddress.15 ifType.15 ifSpeed.15 ifDescr.15 ifOperStatus.15
ifPhysAddress.16 ifType.16 ifSpeed.16 ifDescr.16 ifOperStatus.16
ifPhysAddress.17 ifType.17 ifSpeed.17 ifDescr.17 ifOperStatus.17
ifPhysAddress.18 ifType.18 ifSpeed.18 ifDescr.18 ifOperStatus.18
ifPhysAddress.19 ifType.19 ifSpeed.19 ifDescr.19 ifOperStatus.19
ifPhysAddress.20 ifType.20 ifSpeed.20 ifDescr.20 ifOperStatus.20
ifPhysAddress.21 ifType.21 ifSpeed.21 ifDescr.21 ifOperStatus.21
ifPhysAddress.22 ifType.22 ifSpeed.22 ifDescr.22 ifOperStatus.22
ifPhysAddress.23 ifType.23 ifSpeed.23 ifDescr.23 ifOperStatus.23
ifPhysAddress.24 ifType.24 ifSpeed.24 ifDescr.24 ifOperStatus.24</br>
```

Comment: But what I want is the output of the commnad `snmpget .....` that's why it's on backquotes. I have to seperated into sets of 12 because i can only sent a certain number of request per commnad . But $rtable should conatin the concat output of all in order to later parse it.

Comment: Ah, I thought they deprecated that behaviour ages ago.  In that case, run the above, and it should prove to you that $ifoids is getting cleared down.  Example output added above.  If that isn't what you expect, an example of the command(s) you want to generate would be good.

Comment: Its true. However for some reason the output of the command the second time , is the same as the first one as if it used the first value, Probably that 's why I thought it was a problem with the assignment.  It probably is something with the backquoting instead.

Comment: It certainly would appear to be a problem with the command, I'm not sure that backquoting will be the cause, it should be the same as a standard terminal execution.  If in doubt, execute the command manually and check the response.

Comment: I did , The response is supposed to be different.

Comment: Ah well, this question's slightly tainted now.  If you re-post with the new, modified question, you might have better luck :)

Comment: Fixed it, it was the command, was throwing an error if gave many variables

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code:

```
for($i=1; $i <= 25; $i++){
        $ifoids = $ifoids." ifPhysAddress.$i "."ifType.$i "."ifSpeed.$i "."ifDescr.$i "."ifOperStatus.$i";
        if($i%12==0){
            $rtable="snmpget -Os -Ov -Oe -Oq -Ot -v 1 -c public $ip $ifoids";
            $ifoids="";
            echo $i.": ".$rtable."</br>";       
        }
}
```

it has been reset properly, but because you concatenate $rtable with it self it look like not working